# Does "mislead" imply intent?

Tags: verbs, semantics

Someone is saying that he feels "misled" due to false or imprecise information given to him. Does that choice of words imply that from his perspective this false information was given  intentionally or at least carelessly?

Comment: What did you find when you looked up 'misled' in a dictionary?

Comment: Used without qualification it generally implies intent.  But "unintentionally misled" is often used when the actions of the misleader were apparently not intentional, and "intentionally misled" is sometimes used to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks that, idiomatically, someone may mislead without malicious intent. [Irish Examiner quote](https://www.irishexaminer.com/breakingnews/ireland/it-would-never-be-my-intention-to-mislead-this-house-harris-apology-over-hospital-cost-903955.html).

Comment: So I see my answer in favor of yes on the basis of the body of the question and I see that the answer in favor of no is rooted in the title of the question, but after looking carefully I think the question is actually forked in two -- that is, which are you actually asking? If the word "mislead" implies intent, or if the choice of words "I feel misled" implies a perspective that the speaker feels that the misleading was intentional? Because those answers are "no" and "yes," respectively.

Comment: So allow me to pun here, but, your question and your body don't match... So, this is a ***misleading*** question.

Comment: @psosuna You think so? Can you propose a better question title?

Comment: @realtime I suppose so, but it really depends which of the two you'd like answered! So, say for example, if your question is what's in the body, I might title it 'Do the words "I feel misled" imply a feeling of  intent, with respect to the speaker's point of view?' But then again, only you know what you mean to ask. I hope you're not taking the tongue-in-cheek pun as rude, by the way. If so, I apologize.

Comment: Are we in a court of law, or some other specialized environment? The word has technical meanings, so the context of usage is *very* important.

Comment: *Does “mislead” imply intent?* - well yeah, **IF it was done intentionally**. (we're not here to "argue" - VTCed as unclear;  define *mislead*. Now, what's the question?)

Comment: If the answer is, [*It's an ambiguous statement.*] then it's not a very good question. (unless you can provide a definition connoting utter and intentional ambiguity - but most words generally are, by themselves. Your job as a user of language is to not be ambiguous, unless that's intentional, and it is certainly not my job to put more words in someone else's mouth.

Comment: Of course - the act of leading to a destination is intentional. That much is certain.  Did you mean, "Did they maliciously lead to 'that' destination?" If it's the wrong destination, then regardless of intent they were misled.  Intent is separate.

Comment: Many examples of usages of "misleading" can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22misleading%22

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I would argue for **no**: *mislead* doesn't imply intent, though it's certainly compatible with it.

When I tell someone ["Sorry if I misled you"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sorry+if+I+misled+you%22), I'm not admitting an act of deception; I'm saying that I said something that may have given them a misunderstanding.

When we say ["unintentionally misled"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unintentionally+misled%22&tbm=bks) or ["accidentally misled"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%accidentally+misled%22&tbm=bks), this is not a contradiction in terms; it merely means that someone unintentionally led someone else to misunderstand something. ["Intentionally misled"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intentionally+misled%22&tbm=bks), likewise, is not redundant.

When we speak of a ["misleading example"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22misleading+example%22&tbm=bks), the example obviously has no intent, but furthermore, the person who gave the example usually had no intent to deceive, either. (But sometimes they did. I recommend looking through the Google Books hits for this one; in most cases it's clear that it was unintentional, but in some cases it can be read as intentional or at least suspicious.)

---

**Edited to add:** In a comment to this answer, [lbf](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/277355/lbf) points out that all of these examples have context. This was obviously intentional on my part — the context is what provides evidence of how it's meant to be understood — but it's a fair point that sometimes a word or phrase ordinarily *suggests* something narrower than it necessarily *requires*, such that context can completely change what's being suggested; for example, if I say "We lost the game", you'll assume it was unintentional (to the point that "We unintentionally lost the game" will usually sound odd), but "We intentionally lost the game" is not a contradiction. Conversely, if I say "I turned the machine on", you'll assume it was intentional (to the point that "I intentionally turned the machine on" will usually sound odd), but "I accidentally turned the machine on" is not a contradiction.

I think that, barring such context, *mislead* can really go either way; the results of [a Google Books Search for "mislead investigators"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22misled+investigators%22&tbm=bks), for example, seem to be pretty evenly split between cases of seeming intentional deception and cases where such an interpretation is not possible. Neither "intentionally misled" nor "unintentionally misled" sounds odd.

In your example, "I feel misled", I would expect that the speaker has chosen this phrasing specifically so as to *avoid* suggesting that it was necessarily intentional; otherwise he would more likely say "I feel lied to", or at least "I feel that you misled me." But that doesn't mean that the speaker *doesn't* think it was intentional — merely that he's decided not to phrase his statement in a way that too strongly suggests that it was.

Comment: In further support for the "No" answer, I might be misled by an inanimate object (e.g. a sign that had been turned around by a strong wind), it would not make sense to say the sign *intended* to mislead me.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Very true! Though inanimate examples can be misleading, because we'll often say things like "This door doesn't want to open" even when we know that it doesn't *really* have volition.

Comment: a sign intends to mislead?  anthropomorphism.  All of your examples have context: unintentional, accidental

Comment: Fully agreed. "Lie" directly suggests intent. The context around "mislead" may imply intent, but the word itself does not.

Comment: This answer got many votes, but I am not quite comfortable with it because: 1. "Sorry if I misled you." could well be an ironizing exaggeration. 2. The inanimate examples do not fit my question since it states "information given to him", i.e. there is another person involved.

Comment: @realtime In a world filled with computers, lifeless objects often give information. Signs clearly give information and even when they were correct they can be out of date. An out of date sign will mislead you, but the sign itself has no intent and the people who placed it there had no intent to mislead.

Comment: @ruakh you write "mislead can really go either way" but still you "would argue for no" right at the beginning of your answer. I feel misled. ;) Could you align that first sentence with the rest of your answer?

Comment: @realtime: That first sentence *does* align with the rest of my answer: *mislead* does *not* imply intent, because it "can really go either way": it's equally happy both in cases of intent and in cases of non-intent.

Comment: There is no dictionary definition offered either in the question or in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

I would argue for ***yes***.

Though it isn't for certain that the action of providing imprecise information is actually intentional, from the point of view of the person saying that they feel *misled* implies a wrong direction from the provider of the information to the recipient.

If the misinformation caused the person saying this to be in a state of error, and the recipient acknowledges that the action was not deliberate, and that the information as they received it was of a different nature than their original perception, then they weren't *misled*, they simply otherwise ***misunderstood***.

Comment: I'd argue that being misled also requires that the receiver of the information believes that the giver is under an obligation to provide true and correct information. E.g. if I ask for train times from a member of the railroad staff and get incorrect information then I'd feel misled, if I just ask another traveller and get incorrect information then I've been misinformed.

Comment: If a fellow traveller tells you the incorrect arrival time deliberately, and you impute no dishonesty to them, that's not just a misunderstanding, you've been misled. You won't know about it until you miss your train. Even if the information-giver was completely honest but mistaken, you have been misled. "cause (someone) to have a wrong idea or impression." "1. To lead in the wrong direction." No dictionary definition requires dishonesty or deception to be involved, though it often may be the case. We can see this when when we use the word for inanimate objects: "That photo is misleading."

Comment: Regardless of whether the act of misinformation happens with or without malicious intent, the perception of being misled is personal and removed from the act. It explains the feeling of being deliberately lied to, regardless of authority, and regardless of actual intent. To have been misinformed may often cause the feeling of having been misled, unless the person knows that the misinformation was not deliberate, in which case it can be understood to either be bad information or a misunderstanding arising from dubious information.

Comment: You start by saying "Though it isn't for certain that the action of providing imprecise information is actually intentional". Therefore, by definition there is the posibility that the misinformation was UNINTENTIONAL. If that is so then the correct answer is NO. It doesn't matter that in many cases the answer is YES. What matters is that there is the possibility of the misinformation being unintentional.

Comment: There is no contradiction in the sentence, "I mislead you because I was confused myself" but it clearly implies a lack of intent.

Comment: @RobertCline I'm answering this question on the basis of the body -- If a speaker says "I feel misled," it is removed from the possibility of the misleading being intentional or unintentional, since the question is essentially "does this choice of words show that the speaker feels that the misleading was intentional or at least careless?" Instead, I think you're arguing for whether misleading can happen intentionally or not... which I fully agree with you, in that case.

Comment: If I was giving instructions to someone over the phone I might say "Go along Smith Street and take the third turning on the left" without realising that he was facing in the opposite direction from the one I thought he was facing. He would then be seriously misled; but my only fault would be one of omission for not checking his direction on Smith St, not one of intention to mislead.

Answer (score 11):

Interestingly enough, many 'knowledge'-describing words are somewhat vague. 'True' and 'false' are incontrovertible (except when people are using them sloppily) but between those two there's a lot of room.

When a statement by a person is wrong, there are many internal states of the utterer that are relevant. Of the ways to say a falsehood, in some vague order of malevolence, there's lying, 'white lie', misleading, wrong.

A lie is flat out intentionally and consciously wrong. The liar is a lying bastard and totally meant to say that. "I did not steal that money, *that* guy did." He's just trying to shift blame.

A 'white liar' is saying something that is not true, but mostly when the truth is somehow not actionable and will only make the hearer feel bad. "You'll get back all your money." The bank investigators probably won't be able to find it all, they're doing the best they can do.

Someone who is misleading says something that is totally true but in the end not relevant. It can be malevolent, or it can be done out of lack of knowledge. "I was on my lunch hour when the transaction took place." That may have been true but you could have set up an automatic withdrawal for that time, maybe you did (and were guilty), or maybe you didn't (and thought you had to be present to steal), but either way, it was stolen electronically.

Someone who is wrong or mistaken had an error of perception or misinterpreted facts. "The amount was only $10.00" when it may have been $1000.

**So someone who is misleading may have done so intentionally or not.**

Answer (score 5):

I too argue for YES

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/119742?redirectedFrom=mislead#eid) gives only one sense of **mislead**:

> a. Originally: to lead astray in action or conduct, to lead into
>   error (now rare). In later use (now the usual sense): **to deceive**
>   by giving incorrect information or a false impression (of a situation,
>   etc.); to delude or misinform.

and

to **mislead**. [Longman Dictionary](http://longmandictionariesusa.com/laad/dictionary#mislead)

> to **make** someone believe something that is not true by giving him or
>   her false or incomplete information: mislead somebody about something
>   They may have misled the public about the true cost of the program.

So

> does “mislead” imply intent?

Yes!

- - - *

ps:  Some answers that argue for NO are using *accidental*, *unintended* and **sorry if I**, etc ... are modifiers, negating the intent. To mislead is intentional by my interpretation if its sense.

Comment: In most cases. Usually.

Comment: does 'to deceive' imply intent?

Comment: I don't understand why you finish with "yes" when both your definitions imply no. Your first definition's only word that might imply intent is "deceive" and your second definition's contains nothing that implies intent. My dictionary defines "deceive" as causing someone to believe something that is not true, which does not imply intent. Synonyms like deceive, trick, or fool are frequently attributed to inanimate objects that can't possibly intend to mislead.

Comment: 'to deceive' & 'to make' clearly imply imply intent.

Comment: @lbf I don't think so. You can make something happen with or without intending for it to happen, such as this dictionary example, "anyone can make a mistake". Make only indicates causality, not intentionality. And we often describe inanimate objects as deceptive, such as this dictionary example: "the deceptive calm in the eye of the storm". Surely that doesn't mean the storm intended to trick us.

Comment: @lbf, I don't think so either.  If your answer is incorrect, people who read it will be deceived - but you didn't intend for that to happen.  "to make" *a mistake* certainly doesn't imply intent

Comment: @mcalex noted my format did as you point out.  I corrected. Let me know if it is clearer

Comment: @DavidSchwartz noted my format did as you point out.  I corrected. Let me know if it is clearer

Comment: I'd say that there's a strong connotation of duplicity. But Longman also has the example 'Don’t be misled by appearances, he’s a good worker.' Is there a reason you omit counter-examples?

Answer (score 5):

### It depends on how the word was actually used.

*Mislead* is one of those verbs that depends heavily on context and subject (and therefore voice) to determine whether the action was intentional. Compare the verb *cut*:

> Mom, *Joey* cut my hand! [**Intent is clearly implied**: the speaker believes that the cutting was intentional on Joey's part]
>
> *The knife* cut my hand. [**No intent**: knives are inanimate, and the speaker hasn't added any personifying context]
>
> *I* cut my hand. **[Ambiguous, but probably no intent**: we generally assume that people don't intend to cut themselves, so without more context this is probably accidental; adding context can clear this up]
>
> > I cut my hand *when the knife slipped*. [**No intent**]
> >
> > I cut my hand *for the blood-brothers ceremony*. [**Intent**]
>
> My hand was cut. [**Ambiguous**: by choosing the passive voice the speaker has left unclear who or what cut their hand, and has also left ambiguous whether they are assigning blame]

A lot of verbs work this way; you could substitute *hurt* or *maim* or *burn* into the above sentences (with appropriate contextual substitutions, like "hot pan" for "knife") and get the same effect.

And the same thing happens with *misled*:

> The vile seducer misled me with promises of marriage. [**Intent**]
>
> The strange lighting misled me about the color of the dress. [**No intent**]
>
> I was misled. [**Ambiguous**]
>
> I was misled by my prejudice and wishful thinking. [**No intent, but perhaps some blame**]
>
> I was misled by your tricks and blandishments. [**Intent**]

So for your situation, it would depend on how the complaint was phrased. You don't give the exact sentence, but here are some possibilities I can imagine and how I would interpret them:

> I was misled by the information I received. [**Ambiguous**]
>
> I was misled by my reading of the information. [**No intent**]
>
> I was misled by their false and confusing information. [**Ambiguous as to intent, but definitely casting blame**]
>
> They misled me with false and confusing information. [**Probably ascribes intent**]

Answer (score 4):

The verb **lead** means to assume an active role as leader, and so transitive **to mislead** (and its passive **to be misled** and the adjective formed therefrom as in *I feel misled*) implies a failure in that role of some kind, whether intentional and deliberate or through negligence or incompetence.

P.S. The meaning of the passive form of the verb (*were misled by*)  implies something about the "leader" or that which leads, if not negligence or incompetence, an intrinsic quality that causes the "follower" to go astray:

> They were misled by the ambiguity of the policy language.

Answer (score 2):

Mislead does not necessarily imply intent. It does carry heavy connotations that imply it is intentional, but that is not its official definition. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mislead

> "To cause someone to believe something that is not true".

That is the definition given by Cambridge Dictionary. The example of the word used below is one where the doer has in fact intentionally mislead the police, yet the definition does not state that it has to be intentional. One could deliberately cause someone to believe falsely, and one can accidentally cause this.

This means that *mislead* is heavily synonymous with *misinform*. Their direct meaning is the same, but their connotations are different. With *mislead*, one often think it has been done consciously and deliberately. But with *misinform*, one often think its done unconsciously and accidentally.

> "To tell someone information that is not correct".

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misinform

**Here are other dictionaries definitions:**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mislead

Merriam-Webster does include that misleading it is **often** done deliberately.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misinform

Whilst with *misinform* no such connotation is shed light on.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mislead

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/misinform?s=t

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary's definition of [mislead](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mislead) is as follows:

> #### Verb
>
> **mislead** (*third-person singular simple present* **misleads**, *present participle* **misleading**, *simple past and past participle* **misled**) (*transitive*)
>
> 1. (*literally*) To lead astray, in a false direction.
> 2. To deceive by telling lies or otherwise giving a false impression.
> 3. To deceptively trick into something wrong.
>
>    - *The preacher elaborated Satan's ways to **mislead** us into sin*
> 4. To accidentally or intentionally confuse.

1. no intent specified
2. "to deceive" implies intent
3. "to deceptively trick" implies intent
4. specifies that *either intentionally* or *unintentionally* is possible.

So, whether or not "mislead" implies intent is determined by the context, not the meaning of the word itself.